# Csv Export Script for Active Directory Users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I extract with my script the users of my active directory

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties * | Select SAMaccountname, givenname, surname, DistinguishedName | Export-Csv c: \ users \ administrator \ desktop \ users.csv -notypeinformation -Encoding UTF8
```

In this script I use the DistinguishedName command which returns the CN, the OU and the DC. My goal is to keep only the first OU and delete the rest when creating the .csv.

Example of what the script returns:

```
"SAMaccountname","givenname","surname","DistinguishedName"
"Jean-Yves.R","Jean-Yves","Raymond","CN=Jean-Yves Raymond,OU=Communication,OU=Direction Générale,OU=Elan & Co,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=ELAN-G1,DC=local"
```

Example of what I want:

```
"SAMaccountname","givenname","surname","DistinguishedName"
"Jean-Yves.R","Jean-Yves","Raymond","Communication"
```

TY :)

Comment: Use the filter parameter, and specify the OU you wish to query for (Communication).

Comment: ...Or just split the DN property?

Comment: Do you have an example to give me with the filter please? ty ^^

Comment: stop using `-properties *`. It is horribly slow since it returns everything, even the non indexed properties, and you are only using the properties returned by default anyways. It is not needed. If you do need more properties just ask for the ones you want. `-Properties employeeid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the `OU` property you want.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties * | Select SAMaccountname, givenname, surname,@{Name='OU';Expression={$($_.DistinguishedName).Split(",")[1].Replace("OU=","")}}
```

---

**EDIT:**

To deal with the Users OU:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties * | Select SAMaccountname, givenname, surname,@{Name='OU';Expression={$($_.DistinguishedName).Split(",")[1].Replace("OU=","").Replace("CN=","")}}
```

Comment: Great ! It works perfectly if the user is in an OU create but if the user is just in "user" it shows me this: "Juny.R","Juny","Rab","CN=Users"                           It should be deleted "CN="

Comment: @Chrys Just add another replace in that case. You can chain them together.

Comment: OK :) Your the best ^^ TY very much

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties * | Select SAMaccountname, givenname, surname,@{l='DistinguishedName';e={([adsi]"LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)").Parent}}
```

This uses a calculated property within the `Select` statement to get the Parent property of the DistinguishedName via LDAP.

- Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/830ff383-9057-45d8-ae10-5e567efd36f8/how-to-get-parent-container-path-of-the-ad-user-object?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Hello :) It returns me this : "Jean-Yves.R","Jean-Yves","Raymond","LDAP://OU=Communication,OU=Direction Générale,OU=Elan & Co,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=ELAN-G1,DC=local"

Comment: Are you sure you copied it exactly as above?